# How to clean my GDI objects efficiently and quikcly in pure C++ - winapi (not .net, c#)?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, memory-leaks, gdi

I am writing a program in pure C++ - winapi (not .net, c#). The program has a lot `HWND` objects such as pushbutton, checkautobox, icon (`LoadImage()`), edit and tab control etc. Total number of them around 300, most of them are globally defined, and also has a lot of string objects too.

I check GDI object number from Task manager, it showing 1865 at the start, and it reaches 10,000 quickly after switching my different tab control several times in program, so leads to GDI leaks. Program sucks with gray color.

Now, how can I fix this problem? Should I use `DestroyIcon(icon)` for every icon, also `DeleteObject(hwnditem)` function to delete every object after it's creation or usage (all created in `WM_CREATE` block)? Will this actions reduce my GDI object number and will not lead GDI leak? is there any quick method to deal with this problem? here GDI object number screened image given with GDIView program.

[image: Image is Here]

Comment: It is actually GDI leaks that lead to huge GDI counter values. You should use RAII idiom to manage GDI and other resources and carefully control their lifetime duration and ownership.

Comment: @VTT : That's an answer, not a comment.  (Actually, it's *the* answer.)

Comment: Sorry - tried to embed the image - but it's unreadable.

Comment: Well, you already know what the problem is.  Every GDI object you create must be destroyed again.  When you use SelectObject() to select a drawing object into a device context then you must store the return value.  So you can select it back before the device context is destroyed.  Failure to follow these rules causes an object leak.

Comment: Thanks to all. the program does not have paintings, no drawing, just those plain pushbutton, checkbox, icons, tab, edit controls and string etc.

Comment: hi VTT, how to use RAII idiom in c++? can you me simple example? thanks.

Comment: If you don't do any painting, no owner draw controls, then there must something else which is going through a loop and using up resources quickly.

Comment: GDI object number is increasing even if i do minimize and maximize the program window, why that is happening?

Comment: @Hans Passant , i find something that there is code as: `HBRUSH g_bkground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255))`, and then i changed it to: `static HBRUSH g_bkground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255))`. the GDI object number reduced tremendously, from 1900 to 400. so surprising. GDI object number increasing when i around the program, but very slowly... still need to fix.

Comment: There's a (or many) bugs in your program. We cannot see it. This is not going to produce constructive feedback. [mcve] required.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding `DeleteObject(x)` and `DestroyIcon(y)` methods on appropriate places of my drawing and add-icon code blocks. Now, numbers of GDI objects are almost steady, not increasing.